# Why TreeView doesn't list my subdirectories?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a task, which is to implement a Windows Application.
On the left side I have to have a Directory Tree in which if I click a folder, on the right side it lists the containing files. I tried different tutorials on the internet and this solution was the closest to my problem, but I have one problem. Here is the example structure:

```
ROOT
 -FOLDER A
   -FOLDER 1 IN A
   -FOLDER 2 IN A
 -FOLDER B
   -FOLDER 1 IN B
   -FOLDER 2 IN B
```

So instead of this, my code shows this:

```
FOLDER A
FOLDER B
```

it is not clickable, there is no plus sign next to it to expand it, nothing.

Here is my code

```
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainWindow"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Populate DirTree with folders and subfolders.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="root"></param>
        /// <param name="parent"></param>
        TreeNode populateTree(DirectoryInfo root, TreeNode parent)

        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(root.Name);

            DirectoryInfo[] subdirs = root.GetDirectories();
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in subdirs)
            {
                populateTree(subdir, node);

            }
            if (parent == null)
            {

                return node;
            }
            else
            {

                parent.Nodes.Add(node);
                return parent;
            }
        }

        private void Form_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Tamás\Desktop\Projektek\");
            TreeNode node = populateTree(root, null);
            DirTree.Items.Add(node);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Name="Form" x:Class="SanityArchiver.DesktopUI.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SanityArchiver.DesktopUI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Sanity Archiver" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Form_Loaded">
    <Grid x:Name="MainWindow1">
        <TreeView x:Name="DirTree" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="377" Margin="19,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: your xaml code must be the problem. this is just a regular recursive code which I think works fine

Comment: I extend the post with my XAML code

Comment: How do you expect the `TreeView` recognizes the hierarchy of `TreeNode` ? there is no hierarchical data template! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I have no idea, but I will look into it, thanks